# A modification of the terms of the harmonic series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I reduced a problem to the following question: consider the usual harmonic series $\sum 1/n.$ Now choose a subsequence of indices $n_k.$ Construct a new series $\sum b_n$ as follows:

$$b_n = 1/n_k \qquad \text{where } \, n_{k-1} < n \leq n_k$$

(put $n_0 = 0$).

For example, let $n_1 = 3, n_2 = 7, n_3 = 20.$ Then the first few terms of $\sum b_n$ are

$$ 1/3 + 1/3 + 1/3 + 1/7 + 1/7 + 1/7 + 1/7 + 1/20 + 1/20 + \cdots$$

(i.e., $1/3$ up to the 3rd term, $1/7$ up to the 7th term, $1/20$ up to the 20th term, and so on).

> Is this new series also divergent?

I suppose one could use a comparison test with a geometric series, similar to the proof for the harmonic series. However, the irregularity of the patterns here seems problematic to me.

Thanks for any input.

Comment: As a first step, you can rewrite $\sum_n b_n$ as $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{n_k-n_{k-1}}{n_k}$$
and the problem is now to check whether this is $< \infty$. The first idea that comes to mind would be some integral comparison, as the series does "look like" a discrete sum of the form $\int \frac{f^\prime}{f}$.

Comment: @ClementC. Intuitively, do you think that it converges?

Comment: I've tried about ten times to make choices that cause it to converge, but they keep failing. I'm going with always divergent - but it'd be great to see a proof.

Comment: I'd go for divergent -- something like $\ln n_k$.

Comment: @GregMartin The proof is here at last.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this series is divergent. Consider any rank $n.$ Choose an index $k$ such that $k \geq 2n$ and $b_{2n + k} = 1/(2n + k).$ Then

$$ b_{n+1} + \cdots + b_{2n} + \cdots b_{2n + k} \geq (n+k)b_{2n+k} = \frac{n+k}{2n+k} \geq \frac{1}{2}.  $$

Hence the series diverges by the Cauchy criterion with $\epsilon = 1/2.$

Comment: Elegant! thanks